# in which player i can play recordMyDesktop output video file, which has the extension .pcm ?

Tags: recordmydesktop

I'm new to Ubuntu. using recordMyDesktop to record videos. the output video file has the extension '.pcm'. what is the application to play .pcm files ?

Is medibuntu repository capable of palying any kind of video files ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `vlc`:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

`recordmydesktop` creates a `out.ogv`

Therefore:

```
vlc out.ogv
```

---

In the case of a PCM file use

```
vlc audio.pcm
```

Or open the properties for `audio.pcm` in your file manager and select <kbd>Open with</kbd><kbd>VLC</kbd>

---

*Example*

```
% recordmydesktop
Initial recording window is set to:
X:0   Y:0    Width:1920    Height:1200
Adjusted recording window is set to:
X:0   Y:0    Width:1920    Height:1200
Your window manager appears to be GNOME Shell


Detected compositing window manager.
Reverting to full screen capture at every frame.
To disable this check run with --no-wm-check
(though that is not advised, since it will probably produce faulty results).

Initializing...
Buffer size adjusted to 4096 from 4096 frames.
Opened PCM device default
Recording on device default is set to:
1 channels at 22050Hz
Capturing!

^C
*********************************************

Cached 17 MB, from 1344 MB that were received.
Average cache compression ratio: 98.7 %

*********************************************
Saved 153 frames in a total of 152 requests
Shutting down.....
STATE:ENCODING
Encoding started!
This may take several minutes.
Pressing Ctrl-C will cancel the procedure (resuming will not be possible, but
any portion of the video, which is already encoded won't be deleted).
Please wait...
Output file: out.ogv
[101%] 
Encoding finished!
Wait a moment please...

Done.
Written 2631681 bytes
(2526038 of which were video data and 105643 audio data)

Cleanning up cache...
Done!!!
Goodbye!
```

Comment: I'm using vlc and recordMyDesktop gives the output as .pcm , when i try to open the file , i got a screen-shot of that  message

https://plus.google.com/102109410316822201965/posts/PNfAD2xJ7ZJ

Comment: Use vlc =), I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Nimishan As you're a reputation <15 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)